# Change password for other user account in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

In Linux, I have changed root user password using following command,

```
passwd
```

But, Is it possible to change password for other user account in Linux?

Comment: Have you read `man passwd`? The synopsis says `passwd [options] [LOGIN]` and looks like a clue. :)

Comment: 'passwd user-name-here' check the man for passwd for more usage cases

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, provided that the user changing the other users password has the appropriate privileges - normally granted by being root or sudo.  A regular user can't simply change another users password without elevated privileges or access to their existing account of-course.

Answer (score 2):

As easy as:

```
$ sudo passwd otheruser
```

Where `otheruser` is the name of the user that you want to change his/her password.

The system will then **request you** (twice) the new password.